# Which species is this character and what level scene does he unlock?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

If it's not an Ugnaught or a Gammorean, what is this pig-faced species?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Snivvian, and he does not unlock anything I have seen so far.

BTW - If you go to the menu, click on the album, and bitizens tab, you can find identify any species that has come through your TDS.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Snivvian - In case you want more info.

[image: Snivvian]

Comment: I think this is possibly the most complete answer to the smallest question, ever . . . LOL